# Java возвращение значения из функции

Tags: java, android, методы

Не могу додуматься как вернуть значение...
У меня есть следующий код для получения `html` из `WebView`:

```
final String[] result = {""};
class MyJavaScriptInterface {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void processHTML(String html) {
        result[0] = html;
    }
}
browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
browser.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(), "HTMLOUT");
browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        browser.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");
    }
});
browser.loadUrl(url);
```

Код рабочий, и в переменную `result[0]` действительно записывается нужное мне значение. Но мне нужно выполнять этот код много раз, и поэтому я хотел написать функцию с прототипом:

```
public static String getHTML(String url);
```

Но со следующей части кода

```
public void processHTML(String html) {
    result[0] = html;
}
```

не могу понять как можно вернуть это значение, там ведь `void`... Если же возвращать просто в конце функции, то возвращается пустая строка.
Пример метода:

```
public static String getHTML(String url) {
final String[] result = {""};
    class MyJavaScriptInterface {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        @JavascriptInterface
        public void processHTML(String html) {
            result[0] = html;
        }
        public void getHtml() {
            return result[0];
        }

    }
    MyJavaScriptInterface m = new MyJavaScriptInterface();
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.addJavascriptInterface(m, "HTMLOUT");
    browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            browser.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.processHTML('<head>'+document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML+'</head>');");
        }
    });
    browser.loadUrl(url);
    return m.getHtml();
}
```

Comment: Непонятно, зачем вам константный локальный массив вместо поля String без final

Comment: Это я пытался выносить в функцию)

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял. Нужно вернуть result[0] после выполнения processHTML()?
 Просто в метод передается такой же параметр, который и будет возвращаться, зачем это?
Вижу 2 варианта:
1. поменять метод processHTML() таким образом:

```
public String processHTML(String html) {
    result[0] = html;
    return result[0];
}
```

2. Добавить геттер:

```
public void processHTML(String html) {
    result[0] = html;
}
public String getHTML(){
    return result[0];
}
```

Comment: Я пытался создать геттер, и в конце тела метода возвращать значение return getHTML(); Но там всегда null. Потому что страница за такое быстрое время не может загрузиться, я это так понимаю. Что делать ума не приложу...

Comment: Вообще задача такова: Открыть ссылку в Webview и потом получить оттуда html. Кучу способов перепробовал, ничего не помогло, только этот. Если у кого-то есть рабочий, буду благодарен.

Comment: @Xom9ik покажи как пытался геттером)

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @Xom9ik а какая цель вообще? Если ты всегда будешь записывать в result[0], то значения будут переписываться. Если хочешь сохранить все html, то можно запихивать их в ArrayList - такое не подходит?

Comment: Проблему решил, но очень долго открываются сайты при таком подходе) Решил использовать selenium.